# Polylang and template files

Tags: php, categories, templates, plugin-polylang

I divided the website i am making in diferent template files for example: 
 Category for blog -> `category-blog.php` 
 Category for projects -> `category-projects.php` 
But now I am using the `POLYLANG` plug in to make the translations. I've noticed that while i am creating the respective category in other languages the template does not apply for example 
`category-blog.php` file does not apply to the `category-blog.php` in other languages.
Is any way that i can use the same category template file to multiple categories?? more specifically to the translations of the same category ?

Sorry if my questions seems confusing !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: which theme do you use ?

Comment: I am using a custom made theme by me :/ (made from scratch)

Comment: ok I thought the theme may have a special way of handling. but I remember that for the file `category-projects.php`, the string `projects` is the slug for the category in one language. then if you have the category `projects_spanish`, you can create the file `category-projects_spanish.php` and put inside `<?php require "category-projects.php";`

Comment: That's what i am trying to avoid i followed this tutorial http://digitalize.ca/2009/06/wordpress-tip-using-the-same-template-across-multiple-category-tag-and-author-pages/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a single `category.php` file with conditionals. So, you would have something like this:

```
<?php
if(is_category('one') || is_category('un') {
// your code here
} elseif(is_category('two') || is_category('deux') {
// your code here
}
?>
```

This way you can still output different code per category, but you won't have to copy `category-one.php` to `category-un.php` etc.